# Content-Length header and Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, http

I have a PHP-driven website that uses output buffering, generates the entire page and spits out a couple of headers (`Content-Type` and `Content-Length`) before sending the actual page contents.

This works fine on my local Apache server but as soon as I uploaded it to my web host (also Apache), it failed with a 500 Internal Server Error, which I finally traced to the `Content-Length` header. I simply removed the header (it isn't really important) and it works fine since.

Now I'm just curious as to why this happened in the first place - is there some kind of server setting that disallows scripts from adding this specific header?

Comment: The best thing would be to see the detailed message in the servers `error.log`.

Comment: @Pekka: Unfortunately I don't have access to that.

Comment: are deploying w/ a reverse proxy

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I think it's disallowed by either one of the optional PHP security settings or by the Suhosin PHP protection system many servers use.

I think I remember reading something about how mismatches between `Content-Length` and the actual content length could be used for exploits and, therefore, that both PHP+Suhosin and the browser's `xmlHttpRequest` Javascript object insist on setting that header for you.

Comment: +1 for a possible reason but I doubt that's the reason in my case: I can't find any `Content-Length` header in the server's response.

Comment: It's still possible that reason applies. Refusing to set Content-Length under certain circumstances could certainly be a valid security measure. As for not being able to check your server logs, I suggest running `phpinfo()` on the server and then setting up a test server to match.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you set a response header after some portion of the body has already been sent, you will get an error. It is possible that in production the size of the content is greater than the output buffer, because of which the server started to send data to the client. This is likely to cause the error that you describe.

Try to answer these questions and you should end up with the solution -

1. Use a http proxy and inspect the error response. Do you get some html content along with the 500 error code?
2. What is the size of the output buffer, and is the size of the response greater than the buffer size?
3. Is the buffer size same in production as compared to local machine?

Comment: There's absolutely no content before the headers. As I mentioned, I'm able to set a different header (`Content-Type`) without any problem. It's only the `Content-Length` header that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related but I had an issue where setting the Content-Length caused Postman to return "Parse Error: The server returned a malformed response" on my dev machine. I found it to be caused by a warning being added to the output causing it to be different to the content length I was providing.

Eg the output was

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "my typo" in <b>path and filename.php</b> 
on line <b>123</b><br />
... my actual response here...
```

and my content length was for my actual response text only etc.